# Can't connect to SQL Server with user

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm having problems connecting to my SQL Server 2014 with a DB user from my ASP.NET MVC 4 application using Entity Framework 6.

If I use

```
<add name="CONNECTION" 
     connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then all works fine but if I try with my user it can't connect:

```
<add name="CONNECTION" 
     connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I don't think the connection string is wrong or my setup since I can connect using no security so I'm thinking the issue lies with the user on the database.

The user is listed in the `SSMS` under `Security > Logins` and maps to the same user name against the database with default schema as `db_owner`.

The user is also listed in `Database > Security > Users` with the same name and set as `db_owner` under Owned Schemas and Membership.

I've tried re-setting the password with scripts such as:

```
ALTER LOGIN yoursqllogin WITH PASSWORD = 'newpassword'
```

I've also used checked for orphaned users on the database and master with:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report'
```

But none come up. Can anyone advise anything to try and resolve?

Comment: r u getting any error..if it is not getting connected it should throw an error..

Comment: Agreed, you should be getting some kind of error that gives more details.

Comment: Check the server properties to make sure the SQL Server is configured to allow both Windows and SQL authentication.  Only Windows is allowed by default.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your advise guys, turns out Dan Guzman hit the issue, I needed to set my server to windows and sql server authentication by going to server properties > Security > SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.  Thanks for the support.

Comment: I am literally screaming that this issue was plaguing me for ALMOST 5 HOURS and the solution was this simple... wow.

Comment: Please note that I had to restart SQL Server for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common problem, and usually quite simple to fix.

In *SQL Server Management Studio*, select your server, **Security**, **Logins**, then right-click on your problem user, and select Properties.

Now, select the User Mapping tab, click on your database ("Test", in the example below), and see what rights that user has on that database.

[image: SQLServer]

In this example, my user has some rights, but not the `db_datareader` or `db_datawriter` rights.

Or, to put it another way, SQL Server will let this user connect, but if they try to read or write anything in the database, it'll throw an error.

Hope this helps !